# No developer team error when building for iOS

Tags: ios, expo, apple-id

I'm building an app with Expo for iOS with `expo build:ios`  but I am getting this error message:

> Trying to authenticate with Apple Developer Portal...
>
> Authenticated with Apple Developer Portal successfully!
>
> Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
>
> You have no team associated with your Apple account, cannot proceed.
>
> (Do you have a paid Apple Developer account?)

Do I need to have a paid account or how can I build iOS apps from my mac?

Is there no way to build for iOS without a paid account?

**UPDATE WITH SCREENSHOTS**

Here are some screenshots of the errormessage in the console and the preferences regarding my account in xcode

[image: This is the errormessage in the console]

[image: And here is the preferences in xcode]

Comment: Can you give more information about the problem or some screenshot?... if you already have your developer account in xcode, you just have to select in the general section and signing, your team in order to building and run your application

Comment: What kind of build were you trying to do?

Comment: I updated my question. Did try to do this build `expo build:ios`

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know what expo is. But certainly building for anything but the Simulator requires a paid developer membership, except for certain very limited exceptions to run on a device.

Comment: And the console messages you printed seem to come from expo server, and they definitely imply that you do need a paid membership to proceed.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://discussions.apple.com/welcome would be better forums for this question.

Answer (score 4):

To do anything but run directly from Xcode on a Simulator requires a paid developer membership. Apple makes a limited exception for running on a device. Your situation appears not to fall in either category so it would seem you’d need the paid membership. The console message from expo seems decisive.

Comment: This is a bit dated per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449405/build-an-app-for-iphone-no-apple-developer-account