# Build an app for iPhone no apple developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, react-native, mobile-development

I would like to develop an app just for my own iPhone and download the app on it, but I don't have the apple developer account. I found out that (if I'm not wrong) for an app made with Flutter it is not possible, unless I do every week some procedure. Is there some other tool like I don't know React Native or something else with which there is a way to do it? And if there is, what is that way?

Comment: Yes you can develop a react native app without an apple developer account on iPhone using Expo and the Expo Go app! See https://expo.dev

Comment: You can have a Apple Developer account without having to pay to build for your iPhone. You just won’t be able to put app on AppStore but can put it on your phone.

Comment: How do you do it? Do you have any link for a tutorial or website please? @PtitXav

Comment: You can start with Stanford cs193p. They have been making iOS dev course since some years now. The 2 last year where using SwiftUI, previous years it was swift and before that Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a native iOS app on physical iPhone device without having a paid developer account. In the past it was not possible but Apple changed that few years ago. Currently it is enough to have a free Apple ID account to build an app from Xcode to your physical iPhone device. Note that you still need to have a Mac to create native apps. Check this:

https://steemit.com/xcode/@ktsteemit/xcode-free-provisioning

https://makaka.org/unity-tutorials/test-ios-app-without-developer-account

https://frameboxxindore.com/apple/how-can-i-run-ios-apps-without-developer-account.html

Comment: can I use a mac in the cloud service like macincloud?

Comment: @lailanabil theoretically it might be possible with cloud services with some workarounds but I think it would be very inconvenient and actually much harder to work like that. You would not be able to work in a typical way when using a remote machine. Buying any used mac that can run at least macos monterey would be much better.

Comment: It is important to note that the app will only work for one week, so if OP wants his app to work for more than a week, the answer to his question is no, it is not possible.